# Running WeasyPrint after updating Mac to El Capitan

Tags: macos, mac, python, packages

I recently updated my OS on my mac to El Capitan and since then have been running into issues trying to run WeasyPrint. I have updated macports, uninstalled and reinstalled all of the macport dependencies. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled WeasyPrint via pip with no issues, but still it doesn't run. I also have the export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/lib" in my ~/.profile which helped solve the import errors and allowed WeasyPrint to run before I had El Capitan installed. 
When i type weasyprint --help into the terminal i get the following output/error:

```
File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    import nextline_webapp.quotes                   # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/joshsacks/NextLine/nextline_webapp/quotes.py", line 8, in <module>
    from flask_weasyprint import HTML, render_pdf
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_weasyprint/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import weasyprint
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 336, in <module>
    from .css import PARSER, preprocess_stylesheet
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/weasyprint/css/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import computed_values
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/weasyprint/css/computed_values.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .. import text
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/weasyprint/text.py", line 18, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 43, in dlopen
    raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2
```

It looks like a path problem, but I've tried everything i can think of. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and for me it helped to

1. set my locale in my .zshrc / .bashrc
2. be sure to have all the dependencies

setting locale:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

making sure dependencies are installed:

```
brew install python cairo pango gdk-pixbuf libxml2 libxslt libffi
```